# How to get a date time object in UTC representing the last time it was a certain time

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

Im a little stuck on how to do this

I have a date picker I wish to implement the starting date so that it that should now allow a user to pick the current day if its past 4PM EST or 21 hours in utc. What logic can I use to determine if I should start the picker to the next day?

Im only using datetime objects no libraries like moment.js

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Date objects into Unix timestamps (`Date.UTC()`), which will be number of milliseconds and compare numbers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Comment: This makes sense at first although I'm still stuck let's say I get a timestamp of a UTC time of 21 hours for sunday Feb 28 and im living in EST time zone. Let's also say the current time in my time zone is 9 pm. Which is 2 am UTC for the next day in utc how do I select what the date should be for the picker? Should I just increment the local date by 1 if the time stamp is greater

Comment: You should convert all dates to UTC before making comparison. There is a helper method for this ‘ toUTCString ’ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString

Comment: The comparison is fine but after I get my result telling me it's after 4pm est how should I set the date picker that is based off local time ? how should I choose the initial date/ first allowable date is incrementing the local date by 1 day a good enough solution ?

Comment: Imho your logic should work with UTC dates. So if you have localized date as an input, you have to convert it to global first and after that do operations. And convert back to local time when you return value.

Comment: You can look how this datepicker works https://github.com/morewings/react-calendar-toolkit

Comment: Sorry one clarification how do I even get the date of when it was last 21 hours in utc to compare it against ? How do I create the time stamp to represent the last time it was 4 pm whether it is the same day or the day after (after 12am at night)

Comment: Post another question on SO and don’t forget to upvote/accept answer if it helps. This way you are encouraging people to give good answers. I’m here to help, but also to receive points to improve my SO ranking. Giving upvote is free for you as an OP.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the OP at all.